# Django project without models and data base

Tags: python, html, css, django, model

It is possible to build a project in Django without models ? I have a views, templates(html), css and urls. That site is looking very good in a browser. It is a hairdressing salon website.

Greetings

Comment: Yes, why would that be impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely possible to create a Django project without any models. You only really need models if your website contains objects, like posts or users.

For one example, I created a recreation of Wikipedia using Django using exactly 0 models; since each entry was just a Markdown file, there was no need for any models.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing! Just keep in mind that Django's built in admin suite needs a superuser to access, so if you want to manage your website from that side of things, you will need to put in at least a User model, but thankfully that is pretty easy.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

If this is your models.py file, you can just run python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: You won't really need Django's admin site if you don't have any models though.